# Reload data in Amchart

Tags: ios, swift, amcharts

I'm using this library,

https://github.com/ChimpStudios/AmCharts

It works cool, but i didn't find how to reload existing chart. When i call multiple times:

```
self.mapView.chart = self.map
self.mapView.drawChart()
```

map disappear or it's color set to black. In original AmChart for JavaScript, object has method `validateData`, but this method i didn't find in IOS library.

If someone used this library, please help, because in github author not answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with this specific library/wrapper, but looking in the repo, it does appear that both `chart.validateData()` and `chart.validateNow()` are supported.

[Example usage in ChartView.m](https://github.com/ChimpStudios/AmCharts/blob/cf086fe69d897e973912811cc279018fe4004526/AmChartsMobile/AmMobileChartView.m)